# Need help figuring out the db structure for ticket buying selling module in Rails web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

About the web app, its basically a 3rd party app for buying and selling tickets online for various events. So basically a user can buy and sell tickets.

Now I have users, events, tickets and transactions table.

So can some one tell me whats the best way to handle the selling of tickets in the backend. Suppose a user has 20 tickets to an event, whats the best approach to take the input from the seller? Make him enter individual ticket numbers or enter 20 different records and mark em off with flags once they're sold?

The thing here is we're making the user to upload pictures for the tickets.

Need help. Im puzzled as to how to go about this thing.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide specific records for each `ticket`:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :tickets
end 

#app/models/ticket.rb
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :event
   belongs_to :user
   has_one :purchase
   has_attached_file :image
end

#app/models/purchase.rb
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :ticket
   belongs_to :user
end
```

This will give you the ability to call the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   resources :tickets, only: [:show, :index]
end

#app/controllers/tickets_controller.rb
class TicketsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @user = User.find params[:user_id]
      @tickets = @user.tickets
   end

   def show
      @user = User.find params[:user_id]
      @ticket = @user.tickets.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

You *may* also wish to include a separate `Purchase` model, which will allow you to determine whether the `ticket` has been purchased.

If you need more specifics, just let me know and I'll update the answer.

Comment: i already have a Purchase/Transaction model. And im updating the number of tickets purchased in that. No issue there. Suppose there 20 tickets available, A user decides to buy 10, I update the transactions table and show 10 tickets purchased by that user and update the view to have 10 tickets available. But now, how do i mark off 10 specific tickets/ticket numbers that have been sold? I have a ticket_images table where the users ticket pictures go. those images are related to the event and ticket table through foreign keys. So should the admin in the backend manually flag off tickets sold?

Comment: As of now, the seller just enters the number of tickets he wants to sell. (eg. 30). Should I make the user enter the ticket numbers for the 30 tickets individually so I can comma seperate them and store them in my ticket_number column and them pop them 1 by 1 as they get sold?

Comment: Or 30 seperate records for each ticket?